# Accessing Secrets on Azure Key Vault from Service Fabric

Tags: service, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

I build service fabric application and I want to secure secrets in Azure Key vault, I implement the same steps I do for app service but it doesn't work, appreciating your replay.

For App Service:
1. Configure Key Vault on Main Method
2. Enable assigned managed identity on App Service, applied on Scale set for SF.
3. Add access policy on the key vault.

Comment: What steps? And "does not work" does not give us any clue to help you. Can you post some code? You need to provide much more information if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi @Peter I just updated the query,

Comment: What erros you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Azure configuration (VM Scale set + Key vault):

```
Login-AzureRmAccount # Login into Azure account

$targetRg = "testfabric-rg" # Target resource group name
$targetVmss = "jxewcyinq" # Target virtual machine scale set name
$targetKeyVault = "az-ure-two20190115153549" # Target Key Vault name

# 1. Enable Managed Identity for target Virtual Machine Scale Set
Update-AzureRmVmss `
    -ResourceGroupName $targetRg `
    -VMScaleSetName $targetVmss `
    -IdentityType SystemAssigned
# 2. Retrieve virtual machine scale set
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss `
    -ResourceGroupName $targetRg `
    -Name $targetVmss
# 3. Create new Key vault access policy allowing Virtual Machine Scale Set to read secrets by their IDs
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy `
    -VaultName $targetKeyVault `
    -ObjectId $vmss.Identity.PrincipalId `
    -PermissionsToSecrets Get # set only necessary permissions!
```

2) Get key vault secret when using C#:

```
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;

public async Task<string> GetSecretById(string id)
{
    // URL of the target Key Vault
    var keyVaultUrl = "https://az-ure-two20190115153549.vault.azure.net";

    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

    var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{keyVaultUrl}/secrets/{id}");

    return secret.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicklaus. Great to see this clear explanation.

Comment: @ABDULAZIZBIRHANU please mark question as resolved if the answer solves your issue